# JasperReports failing on a linux machine

Tags: linux, jasper-reports, itext, java, jasper-plugin

I have a dev PC with Win7 and `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)` installed and a test server with Ubuntu and `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.3) (6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1 ~12.04.1).` I also have a Grails application with a `jasper` plugin to print some pdf files. While it works on the dev PC, on the test server it fails with this exception:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NoSuchMethodError occurred when processing request: [GET] /test/printer/print
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [print] of controller [com.***.PrinterController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
```

I have read so far that this may be caused by an inapropriate version of `iText` library, but the same `itext.jar` is included into the plugin on both machines. I'll appreciate any ideas that may help make this plugin work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally discovered that the project had a `pdf 0.6` plugin that contained an `itext 2.0.8` library which was used instead of the expected `itext 2.1.7`